# Show playlist and other items in Cars display

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I noticed in my new car that Apple's Music Player shows functions like Playlist, Search and others in my car's display. My own app uses `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` to show album title, track title and other stuff, but I see nothing in the documentation about how to manage these other menu items. I also notice that my car says "Next Track" and "Previous Track" (or something like that), whereas Music Player shows the next and previous track titles.

Here is my question: is this extra functionality exposed in API somewhere? If so where?

(My assumption is that it is SPI, but I hope I am wrong!)

BTW: My car does NOT have CarPlay.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is Apple. It seems they have not released to the developers the API yet.

You can ask for more informations with your developer account here : https://developer.apple.com/contact/carplay/
and explain why your application may be supported by Car Play.

Unfortunately we all may have to wait the next WWDC or the next one...

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 12, the CarPlay APIs for writing audio and navigation apps have been finally released. You can develop for both the simulator and the car without Apple's blessing, however to publish such an app, you still need to request the necessary entitlements on a per-app basis.

(Personal addendum: It took me 2 years to get *certified* for my CarPlay audio app, so you need to have a **bit of patience**).

Comment: One addition to anyone that stumbles on this answer. It took me about a week to get certified for CarPlay audio - but I requested this from an Ltd I work for. So your mileage will vary in how long this takes, but it may well take longer if you are requesting it as an individual, rather than as a company.